# Can I use Sn only solder for PCBs?

Tags: soldering, raspberry-pi, breakout

I bought the Raspberry Pi cobbler kit a while ago, and I needed to solder a part together. The local hardware store (Useless ACE) only has a specific solder, which has just Sn, a diameter of 1.0mm and 2.0% Flux. I'm unsure if this is suited for the job; since the [wiki page for solder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder) says that Sn only solder is used in food processing equipment.

Comment: Ah, thanks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder

Comment: Isn't that copper piping Solder? Don't you have a radioshack nearby?

Comment: Heh, I'm not in the States

Answer (score 4):

Note that the melting point of pure tin at 232°C is more than 50°C higher than eutectic tin-lead solder. This can be very stressful on both components and the PCB itself. In other words, not recommended.